# Extracting and accessing files in the cloud without taking up hard drive space

Tags: python, cloud, extract, dropbox

I have compressed files that are simply too big for me to extract to my local drive.

Thus, I would like to first extract the compressed files to be stored in any cloud service provider, and then access it using Python with something like...

```
fl = open('Dropbox\\myfile.txt')
for line in fl:
    #do something
fl.close()
```

I am a little confused as to [whether this can even be done](https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/202831809-Dropbox-files-taking-up-hard-drive-space?input_string=Does%20extracting%20a%20file%20into%20Dropbox%20take%20up%20Hard%20Drive%20space%3F) using Dropbox or not. I know that I can extract files to my local hard drive using 7-Zip (as shown below) and then use the above coding to access it, but I believe that this would use up all my hard drive space.

[image]

Comment: As an alternative you could also use the Dropbox API, but this would obviously not be very efficient if the file is already on your harddrive.
https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/start/python

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not possible using Dropbox since it is not compatible with a network file system: https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/89

Comment: Could I accomplish this with an external hard drive?